# Extracting numbers from a fixed format String

Tags: java, string, split

I have fixed format for a `String` that will be always: **SPXXX-SPYYY.zip**

I need to extract *XXX* and *YYY* from the `String`, but if for example *XXX* is 003 then I want to have **3** and **not 003**. (The same for *YYY*).

I've wrote these two codes:

**1.**

```
String st = "SP003-SP012.zip";
String[] splitted = st.split("\\.");
splitted = splitted[0].split("-");  
splitted = splitted[0].split("P");
Integer in = new Integer(splitted[1]);
System.out.println(in); //Will print 3
//The same for the other part of the String
```

**2.**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(st);
int num = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
   num = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
   System.out.println(num);
}
```

- Why the second code returns only the first number? (*XXX*) and misses the second?
- What code is better for this purpose?

Comment: Your first code (split) and the 2nd one already use regexes!!

Comment: @Juvanis I misunderstood myself :) fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's always the same format, then why not just use `substring`?

```
String str = "SP003-SP456.zip";
int xxx = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(2, 5));
int yyy = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(8, 11));
```

Or, if those *XXX* and *YYY* are not necessarily numbers, then just add `try-catch`:

```
String str = "SP003-SP456.zip";
int xxx, yyy;

try {
    int xxx = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(2, 5));
}
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
   xxx = 0;
}

try {
    int yyy = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(8, 11));
}
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
   yyy = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why the second code returns only the first number? (XXX) and misses the second?

Because your regular expression only defines that it's expecting to see one series of digits, and has only one capture group to capture them. The regular expression expects to see letters followed by digits, and only finds one thing that matches that. (Once the first bit is consumed, there are no letters left, so nothing matches your `[a-zA-Z]+`.) Rather than trying to run the matcher repeatedly, I'd probably define a single regular expression that matched both bits:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).*");
```

...and use the resulting two capture groups. (Also note you can use `\d` to match a digit:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+(\\d+)-(\\d+).*");
```

...but that's a side note.)

> Is using a regex for this purpose is better than the first code I suggested?

That's up to you, it's a judgement call. For this specific case, if the format really is invariant, I'd go with [Aleks G's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15085414/157247).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+0*(\\d+)-[a-zA-Z]+0*(\\d+).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(st);
if (matcher.matches()) {
   int num1 = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
   int num2 = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
   System.out.println(num1+" - "+num2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why the second code returns only the first number? (XXX) and misses
>   the second?

If you look at your pattern - `"^[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+).*"`, it has an anchor `caret - ^` at the beginning. That means, your pattern will only be searched at the beginning of the string. And that is why you got only first number corresponding to `SPXXX` which is found at the beginning of the string `"SPXXX-SPYYY"`, and not for the pattern `SPYYY`, since it is not at the beginning, and hence won't be matched.

You can remove the `caret (^)`, and you don't want that `.*` at the end, since you are using [`Matcher#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+)");
```

But, given that your string will always be in the same format, you can even use a *simpler pattern*:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
```

and get the *group 1* from the *matcher*.

> What code is better for this purpose?

I would go with the 2nd approach. Splitting string may not work always, and will become complicated as the string grows. You should only use `split` when you actually want to split your string on some delimiter. In this case, you don't want to split the string, rather you want to extract a particular pattern. And the 2nd approach is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Define the pattern like this `Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+)");`

For the example string the `matcher` matches `SPXXX` and `SPYYY` for the two iterations of the loop.

And `group(1)` returns `XXX` and `YYY` for the two cases respectively.